# Problem with stuttering video - 16.04 & Nvidia 390

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, nvidia-geforce

I have a machine with a **GeForce GTX 1050 Ti**.  It previously had Mint on it, and after running fine for a long time, at some point (possibly after an upgrade, but unsure) there became a stuttering in the video. It's essentially an intermittent freeze every couple of seconds.  After doing a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04, and installing Nvidia drivers, I am seeing the exact same behavior. I have captured the behavior in this YouTube video as it is running **glxgears**.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ICiWXRJM2A

This stuttering behavior does not happen with the default drivers, and only begins after installing the Nvidia drivers.  Even dragging the cursor across the screen, it pauses at each one of those 'interuptions', which makes it nearly impossible to use.

I have already tried purging Nvidia drivers and reinstalling, and the behavior returns.  I would appreciate any advice that would help me get to the bottom of it.

Answer (score 0):

What drivers are you using for the 1050Ti? try one from `ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`
or you can do `sudo apt remove nvidia*` or `sudo apt remove ubuntu-drivers` then reinstall it.